# WordPress plugin for simple tabular page view count (admin)

Tags: gratis, wordpress, statistics

Looking through the many available WordPress plugins I still have not found one that gives **only** the admin (or let's say all users that have access to the WP backend) a simple list of post titles + view counts. I do not want readers to see the counts.

- Tabular view
- Simple sort options (alphabetic/count/date)
- Free
- Page names instead of post titles is fine too
- Should list both *pages* and *posts*

Optionally

- Limited to a period (e.g. last month/year)
- Categorized by WP category or tag

Of course I can go to Google Analytics, but I want something much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

[**WP-PostViews**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postviews/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/lesterchan/wp-postviews/)) is a free WordPress plugin that adds a sortable “Views” column to the list of posts and the list of pages in the WP backend. Filtering by category should possible, simply because the WP backend post table has this feature by default.

Limiting to a certain time period or categorizing by tag is sadly not possible.

---

The plugin appears to have been supported by the developer continuously over the last 8 years, so I believe the risk of it getting abandoned is fairly small.

After a quick look at the source code I believe that indeed all the plugin does is increase a simple counter variable stored in the database whenever a post or page is accessed – so no user tracking, storing of IPs, cookies, etc. Please do not take my word for it (as I might have overlooked something or it might change in the future), but currently, this plugin also seems like a highly privacy-friendly option to get page statistics (unlike many of the popular web statistics tools).

Answer (score -1):

**Admin Management Xtended** has feature of renaming tags, assigning , sorting etc. Install and check the site for features.{https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-management-xtended/}

You can try **Featured Image Column**, it's free .
https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-column/

Alternatively, you can try **Admin Columns**, it's free. The Pro version of this have Sortable, filterable and editable columns & import/export feature.
Open Wordpress Official site and search for 'codepress-admin-columns'. I'm unable to post due to new account restrictions.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything in your answer regarding *view counts*, neither do any of the mentioned plugins.